# Vue router and setTimeout

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, settimeout

I have Vue 3-pages application with VueRouter. On the first page I asked a server every minute using setTimeout. On move to the next page timer is lost and reinitialized anew on first page open again. I want timer to coninue working in background. Is it possible and how to do it done?

Comment: I would recommend using `vuex` to start the timer. and also as a bonus try using `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` because this is `setInterval` purpose.

Comment: `vuex` would be overkill for this.

Comment: In my case setTimeout is much better then setInterval. I need fixed interval between ajax calls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the timer in your root component (e.g., `App.vue`), since that component will always exist:

```js
export default {
  mounted() {
    const pages = [ '/page1', '/page2', '/page3' ]
    let currentPage = 0
    this._timerId = setInterval(() => {
      this.$router.push(pages[currentPage++ % pages.length])
    }, 3000) // every 3 seconds
  },
  // Vue 2
  beforeDestroy() {
    clearInterval(this._timerId)
  },
  // Vue 3
  unmounted() {
    clearInterval(this._timerId)
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/advance-page-on-timer-xel0e?file=/src/App.vue)